# How can add table pagination using vueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I have a data table that displays multiple records in one page.. I need to do the following:

1- Pagination of the data table pages.

2-  Display 10 records per page and give the user the ability to increase this number. For example.. (10, 20, 50, 100) records per page.

How can I do it using VueJS?

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <thead>
 <tr>
<th>#</th>
          <th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Date & Time</th>                                        
 </thead>
 
 <tbody>
 <tr>                                                    <td>1</td>
       <td>Sara</td>                                                <td>example1@example.com</td>
 <td>12/2/2021 16:40</td>
                                           
 </tr>
 
<tr>
<td>2</td>
 <td>Safa</td>                                                <td>example2@example.com</td>
<td>24/2/2021 08:40</td>
 
 </tr>
 
 </tbody>
 </table>
 

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-4">
                    Showing 10 out of 100
                </div>
 <div class="col-8 text-end">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">3</button>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle this a number of ways.  To start, you could keep all of your logic in your current file, open a script block, define a Vue instance, set up a data object, define a data variable for the number of items per page as well as anything else you want to track.

Then, you'll use a v-model binding on an input field in your template, which you would need to read the Vue docs to get a better handle on (very good documentation available).  Keep it simple to start. Don't have pagination, just begin with an input field in which your user enters the number of items that should render in the table. Get that working.  Then, shift to a drop-down with multiple defined options, which again you could define in the data object and iterate through those (new now) in your template using a v-for loop.  You can use a prebuilt dropdown with any number of Vue UI libraries like Vuetify or VueBoostrap or many others.  You'll need to read their respective documentation, but it's pretty straight forward.

Then to add pagination, you'd need to learn about routing and route parameters and how to send such parameters to your API as params on the get request.  Axios can handle this for you.

Sounds like you need to start with basics and get comfortable with simple projects.  Building fully functional data tables are quite hard!  There are many great libraries available for VueJS that help you with data tables, even large commercial ones as well.

Read the documentation and watch YT tutorials before tackling complex stuff.  To be sure, tables are well suited for components as opposed to single templates.  You would need to learn how to separate out logic, e.g. a dropdown component.  Take your time and keep learning!

Here would be a list of table related projects to help you understand, see their docs and examples:
https://awesome-vue.js.org/components-and-libraries/ui-components.html#table

-Marcus